Установить время последнего изменения страницы
В php
header("Last-Modified: ".date('D, d M Y H:i:s', $news['time_upd'])." GMT");

В заголовках нету строчки Last-Modified и https://last-modified.com/, тоже не находит. В чем тут дело?
Простой скрипт: site.ru/s.php
В ответе заголовка нет
<?php 
   
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time())." GMT");
    die('1');

?>

В ответе есть заголовок:
<?php 

    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time())." GMT");
    die();

?>

Точно также с print

Ну а любые другие заголовки, установленные через header(), есть?

Не смотрел, но кажется понял в чем дело, но не точно. Если пустой php скрипт в котором только заголовок, в ответе он есть. Как только вывести через die('1');  просто единица. Заголовок пропадает, а если так die() заголовок есть. Какая та магия...

Что та я делаю изначально не так... Весь html документ либо через die() либо через print() отображаю, заголовок попросту теряется. Что делать, причина найдена, но как ее решить, как мне отображать html документ пользователю. Так чтобы заголовки не терялись?

А вы точно выводите документ после добавления заголовков?

Да, на пустом php скрипте проверил. Все именно так

Если вы смогли составить минимальный воспроизводимый пример, то добавьте этот скрипт в текст вопроса

Добавил, у меня именно так работает, 10 раз перепроверил...

Проблема может быть в настройках сервера. Он, например, может интерпретировать '1' как статус завершения и портить заголовки.
